# Angular controller is not being called

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Angular Js.
I want to get data from MVC controller and display in MVC view through angular js.
My AngularJs controller is:

```
  angular.module('VC', []).controller('MenuController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("ANGULAR JS");
    $scope.getManufacturerList = function () {

        $http.get('/Home/GetManufacturerList').success(function (response) {
            console.log('success - manufacturer')
            console.log(response);
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}]);
```

In view, I am calling angular JS controller as

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar_btm" ng-controller="MenuController" ng-init="getManufacturerList()">
```

in MVC view, the action is

```
public ActionResult GetManufacturerList()
{
    var manufacturer = _vcService.GetManufacturer();
    return Json(manufacturer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

angular js controller is not even initiating.
Any one let me know what I've done wrong in this code?

Comment: Do you have an `ng-app` in your view?

Comment: ... or any console errors?

Answer (score 5):

You missed adding ng-app.

```
<nav ng-app="vc" class="navbar navbar-default navbar_btm" ng-controller="MenuController" ng-init="getManufacturerList()">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I missed that. now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-app directive here.

Refer the below example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello Angular</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="HelloApp" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
        <h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
        <form>
           <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name">
        </form>  
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js">           </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           angular.module('HelloApp', [])
              .controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                  $scope.name = "Calvin";
                }])
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```